# Column separation inside shell script

Tags: bash, shell

If I have file.txt with the data:

```
abcd!1023!92
efgh!9873!xk
```

and a basic tutorial.sh file which goes through each line

```
while read line
do
   name = $line
done < $1
```

How do I separate the data between the "!" into a column and select the second column and add them? (I am aware of the "sed -k 2 | bc " function but I can't/ do not understand how to get it to work with a shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F '!' '{sum += $2} END{print sum}' file
10896
```

Comment: what would I do if I'm inputting the file instead of calling the file inside the function? ie. ./test.sh file.txt

Comment: You can then do: `awk -F '!' '{sum += $2} END{print sum}' "$1"`

Answer (score 1):

To adjust your while loop:

```
while IFS='!' read -r a b c
do
   ((sum += b))
done < "$1"                  # always quote "$vars"
echo "$sum"
```

IFS is the shell's "internal field separator" used  for splitting strings into words. It's normally "whitespace" but you can use it for your specific needs.